# Accessible reference for understanding homotopies and homotopy equivalence?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, reference-request, homotopy-theory

I must say, even a while after being exposed to homotopy I still feel somewhat shaky with the concept. I'm currently at the place where I feel like I can understand proofs of problems when I read them, but am basically at a loss when trying to start a novel exercise relating to the topic.

Are there any topology books, articles, lectures which cover basic homotopy and related $\text{ideas}^{[1]}$ in an accessible way? I suppose by "accessible" I mean in a style that is less strictly "Definition-Theorem-Proof" but more conversational with sufficient motivation/background, and that also maybe includes a bunch of basic "nuts and bolts" exercises to gain familiarity with the machinery of these functions?

As a reference point, I have found Chapter 0 of Hatcher to be more or less impenetrable without already having a background in the concepts. My favorite Algebraic Topology book so far has been "A First Course in Algebraic Topology" by Kosniowski, but I still found his chapter on homotopy pretty dense and not super well-explained.

[1] Such as retraction, deformation retract, strong deformation retract, contractability, homotopic vs homotopy equivalence, relative homotopy, etc.

Comment: Try Munkres, the book on general topology. It's written in a very non-algebraic topology way, more in a general topology fashion, and this may help. And in general, you should avoid Hatcher's chapter zero, which is much heavier in comparison with the rest of the book.

Comment: I think what helped me was when I finally started sitting down and doing the exercises in Hatcher‘s book (in particular from chapter 1 onwards).

Comment: My suggestion is the book "Fundamental Group and Covering Spaces", by legendary Brazilian bookwriter Elon L. Lima.  It's available online. The first chapters covers everything you mentioned in [1].